# Failing import in Polymer 2.x: ("The element ... is not defined")

Tags: import, visual-studio-code, polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

I want to import an element and bind one of its properties. My import fails silently. I expect the value of `userLocal` to be an object. But, instead, `userLocal` is `undefined`.

my-app.html

```
<link rel="import" href="/src/app-state/state-user-local.html">
...
<state-user-local user-local="{{userLocal}}"></state-user-local>
...
<script>
  /* @polymerElement */
  class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'my-app; }
    static get properties() { return {
      userLocal: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true,
      },
      ...
    }}
  }
  window.customElements.define(MyApp.is, MyApp);
</script>
```

with the following error message.

> The element state-user-local is not defined

I know the import definition is correct because I am using VSCode and when I <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> the import it takes me to the correct file.

I know there is no problem with the `<state-user-local>` element itself because I successfully import it into other element/s in the app and obtain the expected value of `userLocal` there.

This problem sounds like what is described at the following links.

- [The element xxx is not defined (issue #54)](https://github.com/Polymer/vscode-plugin/issues/54)
- [Recognize elements registered with MyElem.is (issue #540)](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-analyzer/pull/540)

The first link discusses using "`/* @polymerElement */` above the class" which is what I have tried (see above code) without success.

Comment: Do you have a repro?

Comment: Try to change `href="/src/app-state/state-user-local.html"` with `href="./src/app-state/state-user-local.html"` or `href="src/app-state/state-user-local.html"` .. Sometime, this path may not point the file.
 somehow.

Comment: @HakanC: The two paths you suggest point to the same location as each other. But that location is different than the correct location contained in the original question. The leading slash `/` actually means something important in the path definition. It tells the browser to start at the root directory of the file tree. Both omitting the slash and/or using a leading dot `.` both mean to start the path at the current directory. As mentioned in the question, I can confirm I have the correct path because command+click in VSCode forwards me to the correct file path (import reference) location.

Comment: I think, from above error ref.  your path is not correct pointing, now assuming both files are in the same directory. than just try `href="state-user-local.html"` or `href="./state-user-local.html"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you didn't define the `<state-user-local>` element inside your file; you defined `<my-app>`. If you want to use the tag name `<state-user-local>` you need to define it as such.

```
<script>
      class StateUserLocal extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'state-user-local'; }
        static get properties() { return {
          userLocal: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true,
          },
          ...
        }}
      }
      window.customElements.define(StateUserLocal.is, StateUserLocal);
</script>
```

Comment: Although I did not show the code... in the question I mention: I know there is no problem with the `<state-user-local>` element itself because I successfully import it into other element/s in the app and obtain the expected value of `userLocal` there.

Comment: Will you post the code for the `<state-user-local>` element?

Comment: When you look at `my-app` in Chrome, can you inspect down into the shadow-dom of state-user-local?